# A Drupal7 Field that does not store data - how can I get it to render?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, field

What do you do when you have a field that stores no data? The field only provides derived data.

I'm using Drupal7 and I've created a field in a module. This field stores no data - when someone calls `MYMODULE_field_formatter_view` they get a render array that contains an analysis of the node. This is a quality control program that indicates a quality problem with the content of the node.

Everything works fine! In a view I can call that field, specify the `view_type` (there are several) and it works.

Until...

I was in search-results.tpl.php and I called `drupal_render(node_view($node,"qc"));`

Everything renders as expected *but* the analysis field has no html. The title appears but the content does not. The render array for the `node_view` contains data as expected but it isn't printed.

The only thing that I can think of is this:
The field in the node is empty. For example: `$node->field_analysis` is empty. I think this is because the user will never have used a widget to create data for the field because, well, it doesn't need any.

The question is this:
How, when a node is created, can I somehow create fake data to put in `$node->field_analysis`?

Is there a different approach?

Thank you so much for your time.

Chad

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure a field is really appropriate for this type of functionality; fields are *for* storing data so to have a data-less field doesn't really make sense.

Instead I'd advise using one or more of the following hooks:

- [`hook_node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7)
- [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7)
- [`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)
- [`hook_node_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)
- [`hook_node_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7)

For example, you could use `hook_node_load()` to attach your quality data to the node when it's loaded from the database, and `hook_node_view()` to add your extra content when the node is viewed.

If you want to show data on the node edit form you would implement [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide this advice. I'll likely go that way. On a related note, is there a way to ensure that a field in a node has at least one value without having the user add one? For example, is there a way to have a default image placed in a new node in a multiple image Image field? Does the creation of a new node notify it's fields that a node was created?